# Cant create soap client on node

Tags: node.js, api, soap, wsdl

When accessing WSDL api via another tool it is working but when i try to create a client via node it gives this error.

> { [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 161, code:
>   'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN' }

Code i am using

```
var url = 'https://payments.jazzcash.com.pk/PayAxisExternalStatusService/StatusService_v11.svc?wsdl';

        soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
          console.log(err);
          console.log(client); })
```

Using node module **soap**

Comment: Do you have auth/ security?

Comment: no i have no auth/security..

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-parser-js

1 npm install http-parser-js

2 Insert this code before require('soap')

```
process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser = require('http-parser-js').HTTPParser;
```

Following above steps will fix your issue

Comment: its not working in my sails project otherwise i tried in different project it work fine. any solution ???

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is really strict about response format of the server.
I tried `http-parser-js` but it is very sensitive to the version of Node.js you use.

If you need to communicate with the server which sends malformed responses the only way I see is to use sockets:

```nodejs
const net = require('net');
const socketConnection = net.createConnection('80', 'google.com');

socketConnection.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('SOCKET RESPONSE', data.toString());
}).on('connect', () => {
  const request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    + "Accept: */*\r\n\r\n";
  socketConnection.write(request);
  console.log('request sent');

}).on('end', () => {
  console.log('the end');
}).on('error', (error) => {
  console.log('connection error:', error);
});
```

In the context of the SOAP client, you can get WSDL yourself and store it locally and then create a SOAP client.